# why i am getting error for this one like Unexpected template string expression no-template-curly-in-string

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, react-bootstrap-typeahead

```
 <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
  <a href={'/product/${product._id}'}>
    <Card.Img src={product.image} variant='top' />
  </a>
</Card>
```

here i am posting my code i am getting the error while running npm start
Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string

Comment: Are you running ESLint for some reason? This sounds like an ESLint error. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string If so, try changing the `href` value to use backticks `\`` instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace quotes `(')` to a backtick quotes `` (`) `` at your href inside `<a>` tag like this.

Before:

`<a href={'/product/${product._id}'}>`

After:

`` <a href={`/product/${product._id}`}> ``

Here is [link](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string#examples) to eslint doc page for more information.

Comment: yeah i solved it after i posted the question